# ngbuild fails with ERROR: Property '' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having issue with building my Angular 7 app.. when I run this comand `ng build --prod` I get these errors in console:

*ERROR in src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(187,59): error TS2339: Property 'optionIdent' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(192,56): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(195,79): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(208,85): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(208,118): error TS2339: Property 'optionIdent' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(212,81): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(212,114): error TS2339: Property 'optionIdent' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(218,60): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(220,83): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(249,85): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(249,118): error TS2339: Property 'optionIdent' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(251,81): error TS2339: Property 'ident' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(251,114): error TS2339: Property 'optionIdent' does not exist on type '{}'.*

During development my app works... what am I doing wrong in my configurator.component.ts file? Is there something I'm not defining correctly?

Here is my configurator.component.ts file code:

```
export class ConfiguratorComponent implements OnInit {
    data: any = {};
    ident: any = {};
    description: any = {};
    image: any = {};
    weight: number;
    options: any = {
        ident: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        image: '',
        weight: '',
        price: '',
    };
    selected: any = [];
    prices: any = {};
    ngOnInit() {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Auth-token': 'somestring',
            })
        };

        this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}`, httpOptions).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.parseData(data);
                console.log('Izbrana konfig.:', this.selected);
                this.getTotalWeight();
                this.getTotalPrice();
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error', error);
            }
        );
        this.openDialog();
    }

    parseData(data: any) {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;

        let i = 0;

        for (const step of data.steps) {
            if (step.subcategory.length === 0) {
                this.selected[i] = {
                    ident: step.ident,
                    name: step.name,
                    optionIdent: step.options[0].ident,
                    optionName: step.options[0].name,
                    optionPrice: step.options[0].price,
                    optionWeight: step.options[0].weight,
                    categoryType: step.category_type,
                };
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    findElement(item) {
        return Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.optionIdent === item.ident).length > 0;
    }

    setOptionSelected(item, step) {

        if (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === step.ident).length > 0) {
          

            const selectedKey = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === step.ident);
            this.selected[selectedKey] = {'ident': step.ident, 'name': step.name, 'optionIdent': item.ident, 'optionName' : item.name, 'optionPrice' : item.price, 'optionWeight' : item.weight, 'categoryType' : step.category_type};
        } else {

            const totalLength = Object.keys(this.selected).length;
            this.selected[totalLength] = {'ident' : step.ident, 'name': step.name, 'optionIdent' : item.ident, 'optionName' : item.name, 'optionPrice' : item.price, 'optionWeight' : item.weight, 'categoryType' : step.category_type};
        }
        this.getTotalWeight();
        this.getTotalPrice();
    }

    setOptionSubCatSelected(item, step, subcategory) {

        if (step.category_type === 1 && (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === subcategory.ident && e.optionIdent === item.ident).length > 0 ) ) {

            const index: number = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === subcategory.ident && x.optionIdent === item.ident);
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.selected.splice(index, 1);
            }
        } else {

            if (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === subcategory.ident).length > 0) {

                const selectedKey = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === subcategory.ident);
                this.selected[selectedKey] = {
                    'ident': subcategory.ident,
                    'name': subcategory.name,
                    'optionIdent': item.ident,
                    'optionName' : item.name,
                    'optionPrice' : item.price,
                    'optionWeight' : item.weight,
                    'categoryType' : subcategory.category_type
                };
            } else {
                const totalLength = Object.values(this.selected).length;
                this.selected[totalLength] = {
                    'ident' : subcategory.ident,
                    'name': subcategory.name,
                    'optionIdent' : item.ident,
                    'optionName' : item.name,
                    'optionPrice' : item.price,
                    'optionWeight' : item.weight,
                    'categoryType' : subcategory.category_type
                };
            }
        }
        this.getTotalWeight();
        this.getTotalPrice();
    }

    setCheckSelected(item, step, subcategory) {

        if (step.category_type === 1 && (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === subcategory.ident && e.optionIdent === item.ident).length > 0 ) ) {

            const index: number = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === subcategory.ident && x.optionIdent === item.ident);
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.selected.splice(index, 1);
            }

        } else {
            const totalLength = Object.keys(this.selected).length;
            this.selected[totalLength] = {
                'ident' : subcategory.ident,
                'name': subcategory.name,
                'optionIdent' : item.ident,
                'optionName' : item.name,
                'optionPrice' : item.price,
                'optionWeight' : item.weight,
                'categoryType' : subcategory.category_type
            };
        }
        this.getTotalWeight();
        this.getTotalPrice();
    }
}
```

If I understand the errors corectly ther is something wrong with ident and optionIdent inside functions: findElement(), setOptionSelected(), setOptionSubCatSelected() and setCheckSelected(). like its not being defined

Could this also be an TypeScript veersion thing? I'm using TypeScript 3.1.6 (Angular 7).

Comment: Maybe provide some code ? We're not mediums ...

Comment: @temp_user sorry forgot. I posted my code

Comment: You use any everywhere. You should leverage the typing system of typescript.

Comment: @Hypenate what types do you recommend then that I assign to my objects?

Comment: You already know, eg the options, you set everything to ''. You can create a interface for that. Image is maybe also just a string, prices is I guess a number []